# How to change postgres path to recognize perl installation

Tags: linux, postgresql, perl

After installing Postgres on Linux (20.04) I get the following error message when running:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Message Error:

```
Can't locate warnings.pm:   /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0/warnings.pm: Permissão negada at /usr/bin/psql line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/psql line 19.
```

Comment: Checkout this, it may help with https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292167/perl-module-location-issue

Comment: Maybe you have mutliple perl installations? What is the output of `perl --version` ?

Comment: This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 0 (v5.30.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi @HåkonHægland

Comment: Following your suggestion, .bashrc did not have the default 'export'. Even add did not solve the problem @SaromanoSouza

Comment: @JohnKleber What is in the shebang line of `/usr/bin/psql` ? Try run `head -1 /usr/bin/psql`

Comment: This is return:
 root@jokleber85:/usr/bin# head -1 /usr/bin/psql
`#!/usr/bin/perl` 
Line is like: `0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 ago 24  2020  psql -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper*` @HåkonHægland

Comment: @JohnKleber Ok, thanks. It shows that `psql` uses `/usr/bin/perl`..Now we should check that the current perl is also `/usr/bin/perl` .. What is the output of `which perl` ?

Comment: This is return: which perl `/usr/bin/perl ` @HåkonHægland

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$ export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/perl/5.30:/etc/perl:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30:/usr/share/perl5:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base
```

Comment: setting up this path will resolve the issue